# How i can make this code work without of click on the button?

Tags: jquery

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_animation2

How i can make this code work without of click on the button for example when you  want to go from one page to other page the writing in the box start getting bigger ??

Comment: even though this is pretty clear why someone downvoted - it really helps the person posting the question to leave a comment as to why you downvoted to help improve the quality of future questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the same code , without the click handler

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     // this block will be executed  after DOM loaded
        var div = $("div");  
        div.animate({left: '100px'}, "slow");
        div.animate({fontSize: '3em'}, "slow");

});
```

or....

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    setTimeout( function startAnimation(){
     // this block will be executed 1/2 second after the DOM is fully loaded
        var div = $("div");  
        div.animate({left: '100px'}, "slow");
        div.animate({fontSize: '3em'}, "slow");
   } ,
    500) // time in milliseconds , this is half second
  });
```

use a timeout to wait a couple seconds before execution

Comment: tnx Scott i really appreciate it

Comment: @user4833410 - sorry , there was a typo , make sure ) is after the time

Comment: i really like second one

Comment: please upvote answer you thought worthy of one and accept the answer that best helped you to help future people visiting your question

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function:

```
 function CallThis(){
     var div = $("div");  
     div.animate({left: '100px'}, "slow");
     div.animate({fontSize: '3em'}, "slow");
 }
```

And run it wherever you want (in your case, when DOM is loaded):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      CallThis();
 })
```

Comment: tnx budy  i really appreciate it